# Change elements height React Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, reactjs

I'm working with angular and react (with ng-react) and I'm trying to change height of one element to match the height of another element. I have the react component with both of those elements inside, something like this:

```
render: function() {
 return (
     <div>
        <div className="absolute" ref="absoluteCell">foo</div>
        <th ref="emptyCell" style={this.state.style}></th>
     </div>
 )
}
```

So I want to set the height of the empty cell to match the one of absolute cell. I've tried with `componentDidMount` like this:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        style: {
            height: '30px'
        }
    }
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    var absoluteCellHeight = this.refs.absoluteCell.getDOMNode().offsetHeight;
    this.setState({
        style: {
            height: absoluteCellHeight
        }
    });
    this.refs.emptyCell.forceUpdate();
}
```

But I keep getting nasty error `Cannot read property 'getDOMNode' of undefined`.
Is there some other way I can achieve what I want?

**Update:** I've changed some code (updated above) and now the error `Cannot read property 'getDOMNode' of undefined` is gone but now I'm getting an error `TypeError: undefined is not a function` on the line `this.refs.emptyCell.forceUpdate()`.

The height of the emptyCell changes correctly and it all works fine, but I'm still getting that error on `foreUpdate()` method. Anybody have any idea? Maybe some other way to do what I want?

Comment: code seems oK, which ref in undefined?

Comment: I've updated my question. Any suggestion how to do this in some other, better, way would be great, because I've read that calling setState in componentDidMount is bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that wrapping `<div>` around my table elements was the initial problem and it was the cause of all strange errors and behaviors of my code.

Answer (score 1):

The code above is a React anti-pattern:

In componentDidMount lifecycle, measure the height is correct,
however your usage of setState() && forceUpdate() should not be called in this life cycle.
setState calculate the difference and **re-render the react component**. forceUpdate() is a duplicate after setState()

To achieve your goal, please move the logic of changing the style of the emptyCell to componentDidUpdate lifecycle, which gives you an opportunity to update the rendered DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For some reason when I just have setState() without forceUpdate() the height of my emptyCell doesn't change. I don't know why. And about moving logic to componentDidUpdate, I don't know how to invoke the componentDidUpdate so I can make my logic there. I've tried by changing props but componentDidUpdate never fires.